# ApexSQL Search requires Object Explorer to be connected to a database for MySQL

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I am trying to view dependencies on a view inside MySQL database and failing with the following error message:

[image]

I am calling ApexSQL search from within MS Visual Studio 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that ApexSQL Search doesn't support MySQL. ApexSQL tool are exclusively attached to Microsoft tools.
In this case MS SQL Server.

You can check which servers are supported on:
[ApexSQL Search requirements](http://www.apexsql.com/requirements.aspx#search)